# How to keep macOS app process running when app is backgrounded or lock screen is on

Tags: macos, background

I have an app that has some long running processes for generating reports - these may take 5 or 10 minutes to run but as soon as the user switches to another app the report processes become suspended.  Similarly if the user locks the Mac the app stop processing.

What is going on ?  Is this some new macOS feature - I was under the impression processes would continue running using idle CPU time - which would be most of the CPU time if no other apps are running.

I have tried all the power saving and security settings to no avail.  And yes the Mac is plugged in to mains power.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems the answer is to wrap the code in the following to let the OS know you want the processing to continue while the app is backgrounded or while the lock screen is turned on.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {

   let thisActivity = ProcessInfo.processInfo.beginActivity(options: .userInitiated, reason: "Batch processing user report")

   // Do stuff here 
   // e.g. 
   let operation = Operation()
   let queue = DispatchQueue()
   queue.addOperation(operation)
   queue.waitUntilAllProcessesAreFinished()
   //...

   ProcessInfo.processInfo.endActivity(thisActivity)

}
```

I have not tested all the options to see whether they all work but '.userInitiated' keeps running until completion and DOES NOT prevent the system from being put to sleep by the user.  Other options may behave differently.